# Ant / checksum: How to generate one .md5 file for several files (resulting in md5-file with multiple lines)

Tags: java, hash, ant, md5, checksum

Is it possible to let Ant generate one .md5 file for several files including sub-directories, resulting in a single md5-file with multiple lines (each line contains a checksum and the filename with it's relative path)?

In the past, I used the Ant checksum task for only single files:

```
<checksum algorithm="md5" format="MD5SUM" file="${distFile}">
```

I recently tried this:

```
<checksum algorithm="md5" format="MD5SUM">
    <fileset dir="." />
</checksum>
```

But the above Ant task generates one single .md5-file for each file listed by .

My goal is to have only one .md5-file with multiple lines containing the checksum and filenames (with relative paths).

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Write a script that collects together all the individual checksum files.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the checksum task to create the checksum files for each file and then the concat task to combine them into one file.

```
    <checksum algorithm="SHA-256" fileext=".sha256" format="MD5SUM" todir="${dir.cache}/sha/${version}">
        <fileset dir="${dir.release}" />
    </checksum>
    <concat destfile="${dir.release}/DIGEST.sha256sum">
        <fileset dir="${dir.cache}/sha/${version}" />
    </concat>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Mark's comment to the original question, I managed to put the following ant script together (note that ant-contrib is needed, at least version 0.6):

```
<for param="file">
    <path>
        <fileset dir="${dist}/." />
    </path>
    <sequential>
        <local name="md5" />
        <local name="relativeFile" />

        <checksum file="@{file}" algorithm="md5" format="MD5SUM" property="md5"/>
        <property name="relativeFile" location="@{file}" basedir="${dist}" relative="true" />
        <echo file="checksums.md5" append="true">${md5} *${relativeFile}
</echo>
    </sequential>
</for>
```

This script iterates (`for`) over a path/fileset in my dist-directory (all distribution files, so the files ready for deployment) and uses the `<checksum../>`task to calcuate the checksum for each file, writing the MD5 hash into `md5`.

Note that it is important to set `md5` and `relativeFile` as "local" via the `<local... />` task, so the property can be re-set within that for-loop.

The `<property name="relativeFile"... />` task converts the absolute file paths (`@{file}`) to relative ones based on my dist-directory (`${dist}`).

Last, the `<echo... />` task  writes / appends the md5 hash and the filename in the MD5-format to the "checksums.md5" file (note that your script should delete that file before the for-loop, because `echo` does append new entries (`append="true"`).

The indentation of the code is correct: the last `</echo>` must be at "depth 0" indentation, so no whitespaces or tabs get written to the outputfile.

Answer (score 0):

Ant CheckSUm task can be combined with Apache Ant Contrib Plugin.

Ant Contrib Plugin has `foreach` tag for achieving /iterating list of files in directory

**1. Define Ant Contrib.**

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
    <classpath>`<br/>
        <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/ant-contrib.jar" />
    </classpath>`
</taskdef>`
```

**2. For Each- File in Directory to Generate CheckSum For**

```
<target name="checksum:config" description="To generate checksum">
  <foreach target="do:checksum" param="srcFile" inheritall="true">
    <path>
      <fileset dir="${appconfig1.dir}" casesensitive="yes">
        <include name="**/*.template" />
       <include name="**/*.properties" />
        </fileset>
    </path>
  </foreach>
</target>
```

Note: appConfig1.dir - Is the Directory in which Files to be scanned are kept

**3. Calculating Checksum and adding to single File**

```
<target name="do:checksum">
  <echo message="File Found ${srcFile}" />
  <checksum file="${srcFile}" algorithm="SHA-256" fileext=".SHA256" />
  <loadfile property="checkSumFileContent" srcfile="${srcFile}.SHA256" />
  <basename property="fileName" file="${srcFile}.SHA256" suffix=".SHA256" />
  <echo file="ConsolidatedFileS.txt.SHA256" append="true"> ${fileName} - ${checkSumFileContent} </echo>
</target>
```